# Connect to ESX Server with vSphere using Port Forwarding

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere

I have an ESX server that I am trying to connect to.  I have no way to access it currently other than using some sort of port forwarding.  So I am doing it with SSH.  I am reaching the other end and have confidence in my port forwarding because if I change the destination port in the forward to 443 to connect to the HTTPS web interface on the ESX server it connects fine. For the vsphere client I set the destination port to 902.

When I use vsphere I use an alias for localhost which gets me past one problem with how Windows handles that.  However vSphere spits out:

> vSphere Client could not connect to
>   "myalias.alias.com". The server sent
>   the client an invalid response. (The
>   server commited a protocol violation.
>   Section=ResponseStatusLine)

Anyone know why this is happening.  I don't think it is my forwarding unless I need to forward to additional ports beyond 902.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, you need to open 80,443 and 902 ... 80 & 443 for the actual client connectivity - they just use the web services the server presents at `https://<server>/sdk` for the vmware client.

902 is the port they use for console redirection.

Comment: Hmmm... So I guess that means I have to free up 80 and 443 and 902 on the client to do ssh forwarding since I can't specify all the ports in the vsphere client?

Comment: @Kyle yep, unless you want to start screwing around with port redirection on iptables.

Comment: Unless I have not hit the problem yet 443 and 902 seems to be working.  So probably (80 or 443) and 902.